# Error installing MySQL on Windows 8.1

Tags: php

While installing MySQL 5.6 on my windows 8.1 it has produced errors while downloading all the connectors. Please help me to install MySQL and also kindly suggest me all the pre-requisities do i need to install it.  I am using visual studio 2008 and have jdk 8 . I haven't installed visual C++ . please tell which version of MySQL is suitable for my PC.    Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you try `xampp` https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html.
Xampp has bunndle of Apache + MYSQL + PHP + Perl

Comment: Yes, not much need to install anything but xampp or wamp has never given me any issues on windows

Comment: Mark this as answered